# Sonarlint for Eclipse C/C++ rule - Make the prototype of this function visible at this point - not working

Tags: c, sonarlint-eclipse

We are using SonarLint for Eclipse and have some problems with the rule "c:S819 – Make the prototype of this function visible at this point". It seems like SonarLint does not find the paths to our header files, so all prototypes defined in them will not be visible. How do we configure this so that we don’t get this error?

We use:
Eclipse Neon 4.6.0 C/C++
SonarLint 2.5.1